# Tracking Position in a custom UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building my own UIGestureRecognizer subclass in order to combine the tap and swipe gestures and track the direction of their swiping motion. In this intended gesture, the user would touch the screen, let their finger bounce fully off the screen one or more times before returning their finger to the screen and dragging; that is a tap followed immediately by a swipe.

I have been able to get the actual gesture portion of this recognizer to work properly, but where I am finding issue is in storing the trail of points where the user's swipe has traveled.

First, I initialize an array of `CGPoint`s as a class member of my custom recognizer class

```
class UITapSwipeGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    ...
    var trail: [CGPoint] = []
```

Then, in `touchesBegan(_, with)`, I first clear the array if not empty, and feed the starting point into the array

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    ...
    if !trail.isEmpty {  //  EXC_BAD_ACCESS error thrown here
        trail.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    }
    trail.append(location(in: view?.window))
    ...
}
```

I would go on to discuss my usage in `touchesMoved(_, with)`, but this is enough to trigger my problem. Upon the first attempt to access the array, at `!trail.isEmpty`, I get the following error:
    `Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)`

Do I need to make a thread safe version of this array? If so, how should I go about doing this? Or am I just going about this entirely the wrong way?

Comment: show us a more complete block of code - you don't need to include everything, but do show the function where you're getting the error.  Also, which line of code specifically is generating the error - checking for empty, removing, appending...?

Comment: I've added a bit more code to the block, including the function declaration. The error is tossed at the first call to `trail`, particularly in that `!trail.isEmpty` call.

Comment: well, that shouldn't happen!  If you set a breakpoint on that line `if !trail.isEmpty` - what does `trail` look like?  You should see it correctly defined as a 0 values array of [CGPoint]

Comment: How are you initialising the recognizer?

Comment: When I break just before the call, `trail` shows up in the watchlist as type `[CGPoint]` and having 0 values.

Comment: As for initialization, through the Storyboard, I've added a Custom Gesture Recognizer widget to the View Controller Scene, and set its class to UITapSwipeGestureRecognizer

Comment: @dfd It will be tied into some sort of game, and with full tutorial. It's related to sword fighting and I wanted to distinguish between cuts made in time of the hands and body, and cuts made in the time of the hands, body and foot/feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to replicate your error, by adding the Gesture Recognizer through the StoryBoard.

When I add it programatically, I don't get the error.

Here's the Gesture Recognizer class

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class MyGestureClass: UIGestureRecognizer
{
    var trail: [CGPoint] = []

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        state = .began

        if !trail.isEmpty {
            trail.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        }
        trail.append(location(in: view?.window))
        print(trail.count) // Just for debugging
    }    

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        trail.append(location(in: view?.window))
        print(trail.count) // Just for debugging
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches , with: event)
        state = .ended
        print("Finished \(trail.count)") // Just for debugging
    }
}
```

and here's how I access it from the View Controller

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myRecognizer = MyGestureClass(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(myRecognizer)
}

func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    // No need to do anything here, but appears to be required
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I shall be using this in my project going foward.

I was hoping that I could wrap it up  as @IBDesignable to share it with the world, but if that is outside possibility atm, then so be it